# Blade inline if and else if statement

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is there a syntax to specify inline if and else if statement in Laravel blade template?

Normally, the syntaxt for if and else statement would be :

```
{{ $var === "hello" ? "Hi" : "Goodbye" }}
```

I would now like to include else if statement, is this possible?

```
 {{ $var === "hello" ? "Hi" : "Goodbye" else if $var ==="howdie ? "how" : "Goodbye""}}
```

Comment: What you want is a nested ternary. @mopo 's answer is the right answer. But nested ternaries are undesirable, they are hard to read and if you come by this code in 3 months it wil not be immediately evident what you were trying to do. Put the logic in the controller.

Answer (score 80):

You can use this code in laravel blade:

```
{{  $var === "hello" ? "Hi" : ($var ==="howdie ? "how" : "Goodbye") }}
```

Comment: What if I'm going to add HTML tag inside? Example is '<h1>Goodbye</h1>'. It display the tag.

Comment: Then you use `{!! code here !!}` as open and close tags instead of `{{ code here }}`

Comment: {{  $var === "hello" ? "Hi" : ($var ==="howdie" ? "how" : "Goodbye") }} missing double quote.

Comment: This is a very bad idea imo, completely unreadabe, take the several lines, do the `@if` and the `@else` - you'll thank me in a few years when you're editing your own code.

Answer (score 8):

remember not every short code is a good one. in your example there's no single way to hit this `else if` because you're saying

```
if($var === "hello")
    { 
        // if the condetion is true
        "Hi";
    }
else
    { 
        // if the condetion is false
        "Goodbye";
    }
// error here
else if($var ==="howdie")
    { "how"; }
else
    { "Goodbye"; }
```

this's wrong you can't use two `else`s respectively. you've structure your conditions like

```
if (condition) {
    # code...
} elseif (condition) {
    # code...
} else {

}
```

the same in the ternary operators

```
(condition) ? /* value to return if first condition is true */ 
: ((condition) ? /* value to return if second condition is true */ 
: /* value to return if condition is false */ );
```

and beware of `(`,`)` in the second condition.

and as you see your code is just going to be tricky, unreadable and hard to trace. so use the `if else if` if you've more than one condition switching
and revise your logic.

Answer (score 6):

```
<select id="days" class="Polaris-Select__Input" name="days" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="10" @if($settingsData->days == "10") selected @endif >at 10 Days</option>
</select>
```

**@if($settingsData->days == "10") selected @else not selected @endif**

Comment: this produces extra spaces

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is two if else statements in one line. I cant imagine way to make it inline but i would have done something like this.

```
@if($var=="hello" || $var=="Hi")
   {{$var === "hello" ? "Hi" : "Howdie"}}
@else
   {{"Goodbye"}}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code you can write single line if-else laravel blade with four condition.

```
{
  {
    $a == 10
      ? "10"
      : $a == 20
      ? "20"
      : $a == 30
      ? "30"
      : $a == 40
      ? "40"
      : "nothing";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pandit->pandit_id != (auth()->user() ? "not pandit" : (auth()->guard('pandit')->user() ? auth()->guard('pandit')->user()->id : "vendor"
```